# Just finished installing Ubuntu and cannot get any wifi. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: networking, wireless

From looking online, it seems that other ubuntu users have a drop down menu on the top right with available wifi networks, but I don't. Right now I'm using an ethernet cable and the only available options are:

Wired Connection 1
Disconnect
VPN connections
enable networking
Connection information
edit connections.

Comment: Run the command `iwconfig` in a terminal and edit your question, pasting in the output.  Some info about your system and the type of wireless adapter would be peachy keen too.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Answer (score 0):

I think the best for you would be following this official troubleshooting guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

I used it and it helped me solve my situation after installing additional drivers for my specific hardware.